# Asp.net Login control - password text

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, controls

I am using asp.net Login control, and I want to load the control
with default values.
I can access the username text with the "UserName" property in the control,
but I dont see an option accessing the password text. 
How can I change it to have a default value ?

10x,
Udi

Comment: I think it's intentional because if you do that the password will land in the users cache, even if he doesn't explicitly save passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably an easier way of doing this, but according to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.aspx) you can create a template for the control and from within that template you could set the value.

Alternatively if you can find the ID of the control you could set it's value using Javascript.

Why do you need to set a value in this box?

Comment: I want to set a default value, in order to write the label text inside the text box, and when the user clicks on it, clear the textbox (which is easy with js).

Comment: I think you should reconsider your design - this sounds confusing!

Comment: I will write in the textbox something like "enter username" and "enter password" and above the control, in plain text, "press the textbox to enter your credentials". will it be confusing ?

Comment: It sounds like what you want is some form of watermark. I would suggest finding a jQuery method (or equivalent) rather than doing this on the server side.

Comment: Yes, thats what I needed. 10Q :)